# Time Debounce Filter for CSVs in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, time, filter, debouncing

So I have a fleet of trucks going over speed bumps. An on-board recorder notes the time a truck goes over a speed bump, the truck ID, and the speed bump ID. However, due to debouncing issues, sometimes the recorder reads the same bump twice (and it isn't always consecutive)

```
"TIME","TRUCK","BUMP"
"2019-12-06 12:01:48 AM","TRUCK 12","BUMP 13"
"2019-12-06 12:01:53 AM","TRUCK 12","BUMP 14"
"2019-12-06 12:01:58 AM","TRUCK 12","BUMP 13"
```

I want to use a powershell script to filter out that last line following this rule: "Remove the line if within the last X seconds, the same truck ID encountered the same bump ID." I understand how to do simple column filters (-like, -unique, etc) but I'm not sure how to put together this conditional.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This seems rather clunky, but it works:

```
$x = 10 # Seconds of Tolerance
$data = Import-Csv file.csv # File.csv contains your CSV data

$data | Group-Object -Property TRUCK,BUMP | Foreach-Object {
    $dateMax = ([datetime]$_.Group[0].Time).AddSeconds($x)
    $_.Group | Where { [datetime]$_.Time -lt $dateMax }
} | Sort-Object { [datetime]$_.Time }
```

This assumes your data is already sorted by `Time`, which it appears to be in your sample.

This groups your CSV rows by `TRUCK` and `BUMP`. Each of those groups compare `TIME` values and only output the rows that are within the time (`$x` seconds) tolerance. Since the grouping resorts the data, it has to be sorted again based on `TIME`. I believe that's where the inefficiency lies if there is any.

Comment: I think you might have it backwards. My goal is to eliminate the bounces, not keep only them. Thanks for teaching me about Group-Objects!